# Onclick numa option select

Tags: javascript, html

Estou utilizando um `select`. Quero que o ultimo `option` chame uma outra pagina.

```
<select>
  <option>Teste1</option>
  <option>Teste2</option>
  <option onclick="page.htm">Pagina</option>
</select>
```

Isso é possivel?

Comment: Não é possível dessa forma, o ideal é verificar o valor no `onChance()` ou contar o total de options e ai sim redirecionar.

Comment: Pensou mais rápido, hein, @rray

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sugiro juntar algo no elemento que indica essa funcionalidade extra caso somente esse elemento/option tenha uma url.

Podes sempre ter algo como

```
if (this.value == 'Pagina') window.location = 'page.htm';
```

mas isso semanticamente não é muito correto. O melhor seria juntar um `data` no elemento e usar o onchange.

Usando onchange:

```
var select = document.querySelector('select');
select.addEventListener('change', function () {
    var selecionada = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
    var url = selecionada.getAttribute('data-url');
    if (url) window.location = url;
});
```

Neste caso o HTML teria `<option data-url="/page.htm">Pagina</option>`.

#### Exemplo: http://jsbin.com/weyupugubu/1/

Answer (score 4):

Acredito que o que você esteja querendo fazer é um `onChange`, e não um `onClick`. Pelo menos nunca vi evento de click funcionando para `select` ou `option`.

Você pode fazer assim:

```
document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', function(){

    document.location.href = this.value;
});
```

Veja funcionando no [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ymcgjmoz/)

Comment: o `onclick` funciona em `select`, apesar que o `onchange` possui um melhor funcionamento, em `option` não

Comment: A diferença é que o `change` avalia não só a seleção, mas que o valor atual é alterado. Se selecionar o mesmo `option` já selecionado, nada acontece com `onChange`

Comment: Correção: No `addEventListener` não se usa `onChange`, e sim `change`

Answer (score 3):

Caso se apenas no último valor para redirecionar e se ele form dinamico pode fazer dessa forma:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function redirecionar(opc){
            var total_options = opc.options.length;
            var option_selecionada = opc.selectedIndex;

            if(total_options == option_selecionada){
                location.href = opc.options[opc.selectedIndex].value;
            }

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="comboBreaker" name="comboBreaker" onchange="redirecionar(this)">
    <option>Teste1</option>
    <option>Teste2</option>
    <option>Teste3</option>
    <option value="page.htm">Pagina</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não seria mais fácil somente verificar o value do option? **EDIT** A ta, agora entendi, combo dinámico

Comment: `this.value` já resolveria o problema, não, @rray? Porque, ao invés de você chamar como `onchange="redirecionar(this)"` e ter um parâmetro `opc`, é melhor você usar `onchange="redirecionar.call(this)"`. Assim você torna o this no contexto do objeto do DOM atual!

Comment: Se o combo for dinâmico o último item pode variar, por isso optei por esse código senão seria so repassar para a função o valor do option.

Comment: @rray são os problemas de se ler uma resposta pela metade kkk